# Make a DIV reveal upwards onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I found a topic for revealing a DIV upwards but as I am no Javascript expert, I am wondering how I can make this work onClick rather than on hover?

Just in case this helps, the link to previous topic is: [How to make jQuery animate upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468051/how-to-make-jquery-animate-upwards)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: what is your definition of "reveal upwards"? any webpage we can have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WAdFp/4/)**

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {
   $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();
});

$("#reset").click(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

​
HTML:

```
   <button id=slideToggle>slide</button>
    <br/>
    <div class="slideTogglebox">
         slideToggle()
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var isClicked = false; //assuming its closed but its just logic
    $('.button').click(function() {
        if (isClicked) {
            isClicked = true;
            $(this).closest('div').animate({
            height: "150px",
        }, 400, "swing");
        }
        else
        {
            isClicked = false;
            $(this).closest('div').animate({
                height: "50px",
            }, 400, "swing");
        }
    });
 });
```

This is pretty bad way of doing it any way. You should consider trying to use CSS3 instead and then jsut using [jQueries toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
.toggleClass('animateUpwards)
```

Lets the browser use hardware capabilities to animate all the stuff and also its a nice one liner in JavaScript.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Where does it exist?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ - toggleclass cannot animate (at least not until CSS3 as you suggest) - and I just now realise we have http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Yea.. thats why this question is slightly out of date, because jquery and jqueryUI have enough methods to animate what ever you want :) So thats why i said.. he is doing something in between,

Comment: Yes, but your if(isClicked) is for sure not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp) or as posted elsewhere [jQuery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) - Alternatively CSS3 [Example](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/)

or from the questions you posted, perhaps this is what you meant:

http://jsbin.com/ogaje

Clicking the (visible part of) the div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.featureBox').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({top: '-390px', height:'540px'},{duration:'slow', queue:'no'});
    // or $(this).slideUp()
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({top: '0px', height:'150px'},{duration:'slow', queue:'no'});
    // or $(this).slideDown()
  });
});
```

Clicking something else

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").toggle(function() {
    $("#someDiv").animate({top: '-390px', height:'540px'},{duration:'slow', queue:'no'});
    // or $("#someDiv").slideUp()
  },
  function() {
    $("#someDiv").animate({top: '0px', height:'150px'},{duration:'slow', queue:'no'});
    // or $("#someDiv").slideDown()
  });
});
```